# Combinatorial Proof Of ${n \choose k}={n-1\choose {k-1}}+{n-1\choose k}$

Tags: combinatorics

So I know that the combinatorial explanation is has following:

 let there be 2 group A= x is chosen (${n-1\choose {k-1}}$) and B=x is not chosen (${n-1\choose k}$)

 so $A\cup B= |A|+|B|$ therefore:

${n \choose k}={n-1\choose {k-1}}+{n-1\choose k}$

so I took n=4, k=2, x=4 so:

${n-1\choose {k-1}}$=${3\choose {1}}$= {1},{2},{3},{4}

${n-1\choose k}$=${3\choose 2}$= {1,2},{2,3},{3,1}

adding those groups is {1,2},{1,2,3},{2,3,1},{1,2,4},{2,3,4},{3,1,4}

the number adds up to ${4\choose 2}$ but the sum is not disjoint, and the groups are of 2 and 3 elements

Comment: The first bunch should be $\{1,4\}$, $\{2,4\}$, $\{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your line for $3 \choose 1$ you shouldn't have $\{4\}$.  Then when you add the groups, the ones coming from the second line should not get the $4$ added.  You should then get $\{1,4\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}$ which are disjoint and all of size $2$

Comment: but $3\choose 1$ is where we choose 4 no?

Comment: But you are starting with selections of one item from $\{1,2,3\}$ and adding a $4$ to them.  Alternately you could write ${3 \choose 1}=\{1,4\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}$  In any case there should be just three of them.

Comment: got it and as for the disjoint {1,4}$\cap${1,2}={1}?

Comment: There is no need that the individual sets be disjoint.  The need is that the elements of $\{\{1,4\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\}\}$ and $\{\{1,2\},\{2,3\},\{1,3\}\}$ be disjoint-that none of the two element sets is counted twice.  We have that.  Certainly with four elements, you can't have six disjoint sets made out of them.

Comment: thanks!
so what you are basically saying is that Inclusion–exclusion principle is just when they intersection as the same cardinality as A or B?

Comment: I don't understand the last question-maybe it should be a new question.  It might help to use larger numbers-you have $3$ appearing a lot.  ${9 \choose 4}=126={8 \choose 3}+{8 \choose 4}=56+70$

Comment: posted http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839794/inclusion-exclusion-principle-about-intersections

Answer (score 2):

Given $n$ people we can form a committee of size $k$ in ${n\choose k}$ ways. We can count the same thing by counting the number of ways in which person $x$ is in the committee and person $x$ is not in the committee. The number of ways person $x$ is not in the committee is ${n-1\choose k}$. We have $n-1$ people to work with because we are excluding the possibility of person $x$ being in the committee. The number of ways person $x$ is in the committee is ${n-1\choose k-1}$. We have $n-1$ people to work with since person $x$ is in the committee by default and we choose $k-1$ people because person $x$ is in the committee. Thus ${n\choose k}={n-1\choose k}+{n-1\choose k-1}$.